# look for a API/function which is like assert() without abort in C

Tags: c, assert

the assert() function can print the error and where the error happens, but it will also abort the function.

I want to have a assert() function without aborting. I only hope to print the error, the name of the file where error happens, etc.

is there such a API or source snippets in C?

thanks!

Comment: Uhm, the point of an assertion is usually to spot an "impossible" situation (i.e. a violation about the assumptions that the rest of the code makes), for which the only sensible thing is usually abort the operation (=the situation is completely unexpected, the code cannot recover); if you want to continue then that's not an assertion, it will probably be some kind of check that runs some recovery code/an exception that is caught above in the call stack/a message in the log or whatever. You should describe better the situation to obtain meaningful advice.

Comment: Seems like this could be a simple macro to do the test and print/log a message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cunit has an assert that will either be fatal (quits) or not (will continue).

http://cunit.sourceforge.net/doc/writing_tests.html#tests

Answer (score 2):

First of all lets see what assert is

the documentation says

**assert() is implemented as a macro**

and now lets see the actual implementation of assert
something like this

```
((x = 0) ? (void) (0) : __assert_fail ("x = 0", "t.c", 9, __PRETTY_FUNCTION__));
```

well in your case you may not want the expression below

```
__assert_fail ("x = 0", "t.c", 9, __PRETTY_FUNCTION__))
```

now what we can do here now is

something like this

```
#define MY_ASSERT(expr) \
    (expr ? (void) (0) : printf("something"));

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    MY_ASSERT(argc == 0)
}
```

hope this helps

Comment: `printf('something')`, I'm just interested in `something` here. assert() will fill something here. In your case,the programmer have to fill the string.

Answer (score 2):

So if I'm reading this right, your question is basically "How do I print the file name and line number?"

Simple, use

```
__FILE__, __LINE__
```

If you want, create your own macro like

```
#define MY_ASSERT(x) if(x) printf("Assertion! Line: %d File: %s \n", __LINE__, __FILE__)
```

THere are other useful predefined macros too. http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.1/cpp/Standard-Predefined-Macros.html

Answer (score -4):

This is called an exception, and it is a construct that is available in languages like C++ with an optimized implementation. With exceptions, you can exit any function anywhere you want, and end up anywhere up the call stack, without a single memory leak. Of course, this will require you code to be exception safe.

In C, you'd need to hack around with `goto`, `setjmp`, `longjmp`, which would basically be a bad version of C++ exceptions.

See e.g. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/exceptions